# Code example for AWS Node JS kafka consumer to decrypt the kafka message

Tags: node.js, encryption, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, confluent-platform

Kafka producers producing the records and I wanted to consume those records in node JS lambda. Producer said that they are using the confluent Envelope encryption using AES 256 key and they share the RSA public key with us to decrypt them

Anyone having the code example in node JS for

1. Connect with kafka consumer
2. Decrypt the payload
3. Poll records from kafka consumer

Your help much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to currently decrypt just a byte array with your key? If you combine that with any other publicly available Nodejs Kafka consumer library example found available elsewhere, then you should be able to solve the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Kafka JS library used to consume the records but it was not successful. So Kafka trigger is added to the lambda
2. Decryption done using crypto library
3. Followed KAfka Js library example for polling records.